# Python question using map, lambda, filtering and reducing with a function

Tags: python

I want to edit this function so that there are no `for` loops: only using mapping, lambda and reducing.

It takes following list as input:

```
orders = [[1, ("5464", 4, 9.99), ("8274", 18, 12.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)], 
          [2, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)],
          [3, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("88112", 11, 24.99)],
          [4, ("8732", 7, 11.99), ("7733", 11, 18.99), ("88112", 5, 39.95)]]
```

and returns the desired output:

```
['9744', 809.1]
```

However it still has `for` loops, how can I get rid of them?

```
def max_book_product(orders):
    dictionary = {}
    for order in orders:
        for book in order[1]:
            if book[0] in dictionary:
                dictionary[book[0]] += book[1] * book[2]
            else:
                dictionary[book[0]] = book[1] * book[2]
    sorted_items = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda tup: tup[1])
    return list(sorted_items.pop())
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you can do using only reduction:

```
import functools

def max_book_product(orders):
    items = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b[1:], orders, [])
    books = functools.reduce(lambda books, item: {**books, item[0]: books.get(item[0], 0) + item[1] * item[2]}, items, {})
    return functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a if a[1] > b[1] else b, books.items())
```

You can take a look at [`functools.reduce` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce): it receives as first argument a function, as second argument the iterable to reduce and as third argument the initial value of the reduction. Since I think this is homework, the explanation is left as an exercise to the reader.